# Recycling relation names in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Is it a good idea to recycle relation names in Pig? In particular, if I always use one and only one name throughout the script, such as:

```
relation1 = LOAD 'myfile.txt';
relation1 = FILTER relation1 BY ($1 > 0);
relation1 = GROUP relation1 BY $2;
```

is it and how exactly affecting the performance?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely `valid in Pig` but its not recommended. I am pasting the information from the pig documentation link

It is possible to `reuse relation names`; for example, this is legitimate:

```
A = load 'NYSE_dividends' (exchange, symbol, date, dividends);
A = filter A by dividends > 0;
A = foreach A generate UPPER(symbol);
```

However, `it is not recommended.` It looks here as if you are reassigning A, but really you are creating new relations called A, `losing track of the old relations called A`. Pig is smart enough to keep up, but it still is `not a good practice`. It leads to confusion when trying to read your programs (which A am I referring to?) and when reading error messages.

**Reference:**
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#pl_general

Comment: From your explanation it seems that the only issue is code readability, which is open for discussion. My question was why is name recycling not recommended performance-wise?